The Coreml Model I Converted Using YOLOV is Performing Very Poorly in The iOS Application
I converted my custom model trained with YOLOv8m to a CoreML model:
from ultralytics import YOLO
model_path="{best.pt model}"
model=YOLO(model_path)
model.export(format='coreml', nms=True, imgsz=[720,1280])

I set the imgsz to 720x1280. When I set it to 640 or didn't set the imgsz at all, my CoreML model also gave very poor results in the preview section.
I tested this converted model in the preview section with photos, and it gave very good results. However, when I created my application, it either doesn't detect objects in photos taken with the iPhone camera or shows very incorrect classes. I think my problem is related to processing the photos taken by the camera or their size, but I haven't been able to find a solution. I appreciate your help in advance. Thank you.
Request to model:
extension CameraVC : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: (any Error)?) {
    
    guard let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
        return
    }
    
    guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
        return
    }
    
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    session?.stopRunning()
    
    if(layerFlag){
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
            fatalError("Unable to create CIImage")
        }
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage,orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation(image.imageOrientation))
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            do {
                try handler.perform([self.viewModel.detectionRequest])
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failed to perform detection: \(error)")
            }
        }

    }

CoreML Model:
lazy var detectionRequest: VNCoreMLRequest = {
    do {
        let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: bestv720().model)
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { [weak self] request, error in
            self?.processDetections(for: request, error: error)
        }
       request.imageCropAndScaleOption = .centerCrop
        return request
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to load Vision ML model: \(error)")}}()

See Labels:
func processDetections(for request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNRecognizedObjectObservation] else {
            return
        }
        var label = ""
        var all_results = []
        var all_confidence = []
        var true_results = []
        var true_confidence = []
        for result in results {
            for i in 0...results.count{
                all_results.append(result.labels[i].identifier)
                all_confidence.append(result.labels[i].confidence)
                for confidence in all_confidence {
                    if confidence as! Float > 0.7 {
                        true_results.append(result.labels[i].identifier)
                        true_confidence.append(confidence)
                    }
                }
            }
            label = result.labels[0].identifier
        }
        print("True Results " , true_results)
        print("True Confidence ", true_confidence)
        self.output?.updateView(label:label)
    }

